# HTML,CSSによるデザインで要素の高さを70%にしたい

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

html,css,bootstrapを使って、ページのデザインを編集しています。
以下のような画像とセクションの高さを70%にしたいのですが、なかなかうまくいかず詰まっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

恐れ入りますが、手助けいただけないでしょうか？
以下該当部分のHTMLとCSSです。

▼html

```
<section class="section-box" data-scroll-index="1">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    
                    <div class="col-lg-6 bg-img half-img bgimg-height" data-background="img/1.jpg"></div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 half-content bg-gray">
                        <div class="box-white">

                            <div class="content mb-50">
                                <h3 class="mb-15 lg-line-height">Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test .</h3>
                                <p>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test .</p>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

▼css

```
.section-box .half-img {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.section-box .half-content {
  padding: 30px;
}
.section-box .box-white {
  padding: 100px 10%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
          box-shadow: 0px 8px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.section-box .accordion .item {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.section-box .accordion .title {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.section-box .accordion .title:after {
  content: '\f067';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 20px;
}
.section-box .accordion .title h6 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.section-box .accordion .accordion-info {
  display: none;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-left: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.section-box .accordion .accordion-info .spac {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.section-box .accordion .accordion-info .spac h6 {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.section-box .accordion .accordion-info .spac h6:after {
  content: "";
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #555;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: -15px;
}
.section-box .accordion .accordion-info .spac ul {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.section-box .accordion .accordion-info .spac li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.section-box .accordion .accordion-info .spac li:after {
  content: "";
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: -15px;
}
.section-box .accordion .active {
  display: block;
}
.section-box .accordion .active .title {
  color: #fff;
  background: #2AAFC0;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#2AAFC0), to(#6976c5));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2AAFC0, #6976c5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.section-box .accordion .active .title:after {
  content: '\f068';
}
.section-box .vid-butn {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #2AAFC0;
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.section-box .vid-butn:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2, 2);
          transform: scale(2, 2);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.section-box .vid-butn:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
}
.section-box .vid-butn:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

background-imageに対して、background-size:100% 70% にしたり、
divに対して、height:70%にしたりしましたがうまくいきません。
右側のグレイの部分のサイズが縮まらなかったりします。

恐縮ですが、アドバイスいただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

```
.section-box .box-white {
  padding: 50px 10%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
          box-shadow: 0px 8px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
```

にすることで高さをだいたい70%に縮めることができました。